# The net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor attribute is not working for text fields at Frame

Tags: jasper-reports

In my database I have the hex colour codes for various scenarios and I want to highlight the rows using these variable colours.  I have used `net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor`, but all rows have the same background colour which is that of the first row.

```
<frame>
    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{sp_colour}]]></propertyExpression>
    </reportElement>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the engine is initializing the frame's attribute using the first record from the datasource and using this initial value for all other records (2nd iteration from the result set, 3rd iteration and so on). Probably this is a bug of *JasperReports* library.

The issue can be solved using several workarounds.

### Workaround 1. Using conditional style

The introduction of conditional style is resolving the issue. If we have ***N*** unique values of colors we have to add at least ***N - 1*** conditions for style - one condition for one color.

#### Working example. Datasource

I used *csv* based datasource for testing report:

```
team1,team2,color1,color2,duration_color,date
BEL,POR,#0000FF,#7F8C8D,#FFFFFF,"27 June"
ITA,AUT,#0000FF,#7F8C8D,#F2F3F4,"26 June"
FRA,SUI,#7F8C8D,#0000FF,#F6DDCC,"28 June"
CRO,ESP,#7F8C8D,#0000FF,#F2F3F4,"28 June"
SWE,UKR,#7F8C8D,#0000FF,#F2F3F4,"29 June"
ENG,GER,#0000FF,#7F8C8D,#FFFFFF,"29 June"
NED,CZE,#7F8C8D,#0000FF,#FFFFFF,"27 June"
WAL,DEN,#7F8C8D,#0000FF,#FFFFFF,"26 June"
```

The first row at the file contains the column names and should be skipped (for example using settings of data adapter).

This file contains ***3*** unique colors (the field ***duration_color***) that will be used as background color.

#### Working example. Report template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Backcolor, W1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="colors"/>
    <style name="frameStyle">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA["#FFFFFF".equals($F{duration_color})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA["#F2F3F4".equals($F{duration_color})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA["#F6DDCC".equals($F{duration_color})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <field name="team1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="team2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="color1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="color2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="duration_color" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="frameStyle" mode="Opaque" x="172" y="0" width="250" height="20">
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{duration_color}]]></propertyExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.format("Match date: %s", $F{date})]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="60" height="20">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor"><![CDATA[$F{color1}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="160" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[vs]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="60" height="20">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor"><![CDATA[$F{color2}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="20" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F2F3F4"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Extra time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F6DDCC"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Penalty shootout]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The 3 conditional styles were introduced at *frameStyle* and this style is applied for the whole frame.

#### Working example. The output result

I used *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JSS*) to generate the output result.

[image: Preview at JSS]

### Workaround 2. Applying attributes at elements, not at frame

Another workaround is to apply the *net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor* attribute at all elements (textField and staticText) instead of using the frame's attribute.

#### Working example. Report template

No need to introduce conditional style in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Backcolor, W2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="colors"/>
    <field name="team1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="team2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="color1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="color2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="duration_color" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="172" y="0" width="250" height="20"/>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.format("Match date: %s", $F{date})]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="60" height="20">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor"><![CDATA[$F{color1}]]></propertyExpression>
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{duration_color}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="160" y="0" width="30" height="20">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{duration_color}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[vs]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="190" y="0" width="60" height="20">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor"><![CDATA[$F{color2}]]></propertyExpression>
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{duration_color}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="20" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F2F3F4"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Extra time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#F6DDCC"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Penalty shootout]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The frame even can be removed.

#### Working example. The output result

The result generated at *JSS* is absolutely the same:

[image: Preview at JSS]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you Alex K.
The first option of using conditional formatting was not going to work as the users can pick a large number of colours

The second option of applying the net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor attribute to all elements was where I was thinking of heading, but with 2 details lines with 12+ elements in each was going to be time consuming.

Instead I added a textbox element the same size as the frame, as the first element in the frame and applied the net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor attribute to it.  I used a printWhenExpression as the colouring was only required for special make and therefore retained alternate row highlighting for the other rows in the report

```
<frame>
    <reportElement style="Row" stretchType="ContainerHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b9bde183-f2ec-4051-8c7e-22072071357d"/>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="798" height="12" uuid="d110cab3-6534-4c2a-9304-74a11c2a7cb8">
            <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$F{sp_colour}]]></propertyExpression>
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["Y".equals($F{is_special_make})]]>/printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Lucida Sans" size="6"/>
        </textElement>
    </textField>
```